# ordering balls in slots

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Three balls are to be placed in 8 slots.

a. If we distinguish among the balls by naming them $ B_1, B_2, B_3 $, in how many different ways can we do this?

I think that this permutation problem, so the solution is

$$
\binom{8}{3}*3!
$$

b. If we do not distinguish among the balls in how many different ways can we do this?

I think that this combination problem, so the solution is

$$
\binom{8}{3}
$$

c. What is the probability that  ball $ B_1, B_2, B_3 $ comes before the other two balls when we examine the slots in a certain order (left to right)?

I couldn't decide how I should consider the solution?

Always one ball comes before other two so i can say that result is equal to 1, on the other hand if question asks the balls porbability separately $B_1$ probability is equal to

$$
\frac{\binom{7}{2}*2!+\binom{6}{2}*2!+\binom{5}{2}*2!+\binom{5}{2}*2!+\binom{4}{2}*2!+\binom{3}{2}*2!+\binom{2}{2}*2!}{\binom{8}{3}*3!}
$$

Is this solutions correct in a and b? And which solution is correct for option c?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Choose 3 slots - this you can do in $\binom{8}{3}$ ways.
Now as the balls are distinguishable you have $3!$ ways to place them in the (already selected) 3 slots. So in total you get $3! \cdot \binom{8}{3}$ ways to do what's wanted.

2) Choose 3 slots - this you can do in $\binom{8}{3}$ ways.
Now as the balls are not distinguishable you have only 1 way to place them in the (already selected) 3 slots. So you get $1 \cdot \binom{8}{3}$ ways to do this.

3) You have $3! = 6$ ways in which the balls can be ordered.

B1 B2 B3
B1 B3 B2

B2 B1 B3
B2 B3 B1

B3 B1 B2
B3 B2 B1

Apparently in 2 of these 6 cases B1 comes before the other two Bs
(no matter if we assume left to right or right to left order).

So the probability is 2/6 = 1/3.

Same is the answer for B2 and B3, the probabilities are still 1/3
(which is not surprising as the problem is symmetric with respect
to B1, B2, B3; I mean none of these Bs is more special than the
other two).

Btw, 3) implies that the balls are distinguishable.
Otherwise, 3) makes no sense to be asked at all.

Answer (score 1):

While (a) and (b) are correct, I think the answer for (c) is $\frac{1}{3}$. You don't need to consider which slots the balls are in, just think of the order of the three balls from left to right. There are $3! = 6$ permutations, and in $2$ out of the $6$ permutations, $B_i$ comes before the other two.

Another way to think is: As you have said, the probability of any one ball comes before other two is equal to $1$, and by symmetry, there is the same chance for any one of the three balls to come before the other two. Hence the answer is $\frac{1}{3}$.